# Easy way to update a single translation entry without having to translate

Tags: post-thumbnails, translation

I'm using the "Featured Image" meta box which allows you to attach a secondary thumbail to a post. The title for this box is defined in the Wordpress codebase like so:

```
__('Featured Image')
```

Which looks to be a wrapper for the translate methods. I'm wondering how to change this text without having to do any translation files. Is it as simple as an action or filter hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the [`gettext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter does exactly what you require.

Here's some code that should work out of the box:

```
function wpse31449_translate_my_stuff($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if ($text == 'Featured Image')
        return 'Post Image';
    return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse31449_translate_my_stuff', null, 3 );
```

Note: if the translation is retrieved with a gettext context ([`_x()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x) and [`_ex()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_ex)) then the `gettext_with_context` filter has to be hooked to, which passes 4 arguments - the translation, the original string, the context and the domain to your filter.

Let me know if the answer is clear and/or how I can further improve it.

Comment: Incredibly clear, and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing, btw. http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/easy-translation-of-wordpress-admin-texts

Comment: Great post, well done! I like how you found an application for it. Make sure you mention our community that helped you figure this and any other questions that you may have had or will have, though *wink* *wink*

Comment: Oh, good call. Linked ya up. :)

Comment: I meant the WPStackExchange community in general, but big thanks, Benjamin, great blog, btw.